# EF4 Eager Loading via an ObjectContext base instance

Tags: .net, entity-framework-4

When using ORMs I usual create a factory method to return the DataContext / ObjectContext instance that I'll then use to query the data source. I usually have my factories return the base context class; so in the case of EF4 I return an ObjectContext type instance as opposed to the generated "MyDBConext" instance. The method signature looks something like this:

```
ObjectContext CreateContext()
```

This CreateContext method returns an instance with LazyLoadingEnabled = false and ProxyCreationEnabled = false options. When accessing the entity collections I'd call something like ctx.CreateObjectSet() where T of course is the entity type.

I've noticed that when I use the ObjectContext type instance as opposed to a "MyDBConext", eager loading does not seem to work.

```
User result = null;
using(ObjectContext ctx = ContextFactory.CreateContext()) {
              ObjectSet<User> userSet = ctx.CreateObjectSet<User>();
               //userSet.Include(x => x.Roles);
               userSet.Include("Roles");
               result = userSet.SingleOrDefault(exp);                
      }
      return result;
```

But changing the using statement to something like

```
 using(MyDBConext ctx = new MyDBConext()) {
```

works as expected. But why? Can I not eager load via the base ObjectContext instance?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I solved my issue

```
User result = null;
using(ObjectContext ctx = ContextFactory.CreateContext()) {
    ObjectSet<User> userSet = ctx.CreateObjectSet<User>();              
    result = userSet.Include("Roles").SingleOrDefault(exp);                
 }
 return result;
```

I thought that the include statement altered the current instance of the ObjectSet / ObjectQuery and returned it it. I thought thats how most fluent api's were designed to work. Placing the Include inline and chaining the method calls produced the query results as expected. This is an interesting "fact" about the fluent api of EF